# Openlayers 2 aand Openlayers 3 Code convertion

Tags: openlayers-2, openlayers

I have an old Opanlayers 2 application. And I need to convert an Opanlayers3 code to Opnelayers2, but could not.

**Opanlaysrs 3 Code**

```
  var epsg = "EPSG:900913";
  var projection = ol.proj.get(epsg);

  var projectionExtent = projection.getExtent();
  var size = ol.extent.getWidth(projectionExtent) / 256;
  var resolutions = [];
  var matrixIds = [];
  for (var z = 0; z < 28; z++) {        
    resolutions[z] = size / Math.pow(2, z);
    matrixIds[z] = epsg + ':'+ z;
  }
```

I will convet it to Opanlaysers 2 But could not:

```
  var epsg = "EPSG:900913";
  var projection = new Opanlayers.Projest(epsg);

  var projectionExtent = ???? // projection.getExtent();
  var size = ???? //ol.extent.getWidth(projectionExtent);
  var resolutions = [];
  var matrixIds = [];
  for (var z = 0; z < 28; z++) {        
    resolutions[z] = size / Math.pow(2, z);
    matrixIds[z] = epsg + ':'+ z;
  }
```

`projection.getExtent();` is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OpenLayers 2 equivalent is:

```
  var epsg = "EPSG:900913";
  var projection = new Opanlayers.Projection(epsg);

  var projectionExtent = new OpenLayers.Bounds(OpenLayers.Projection.defaults["EPSG:900913"].maxExtent);
  var size = projectionExtent.getWidth() / 256;
  var resolutions = [];
  var matrixIds = [];
  for (var z = 0; z < 28; z++) {        
    resolutions[z] = size / Math.pow(2, z);
    matrixIds[z] = epsg + ':'+ z;
  }
```